# Palm Tree -Stuff Under Leaves

Tags: pests, palm, scale

I have been growing a Majesty Palm I got from Home Depot for almost half a year now. I recently noticed that under the leaves are these small, long, thin white/brown things that seem to be on the middle of the palm leaves. These are not on every leaf, but are on most. I read somewhere that I should wipe them off with alcohol if it was some sort of scale, however I am not sure what this is. I tried wiping with rubbing alcohol and most of them wipe off easily, but some I need to rub a little harder to get off. The plant seems to be doing ok and there does not seem to be visible damage on the leaves with these on them. What is this and is this normal? And if this is not normal, how do I help my plant?

Thanks!

[image: Under Palm1]

[image: Under palm 2]

[image: Wiped off]